# codepush with wix navigation on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

I've been stuck on this for two days now and even though this question has been asked. None of the answers helped me.

I am using Wix Navigation V2 and trying to use CodePush for instant updates. In staging, I can see CodePush logs and updates happen (just checking to see logs). In Production however, my app always reverts to a black screen after the splash. Here is what I have tried so far.

This approach: https://medium.com/react-coach/using-codepush-with-wix-react-native-navigation-a6a7938cee24

I have also made sure my deployment key is correct in my plist file using
`appcenter codepush deployment list -a {myUserName}/{appName} -k`

I have also tried these approaches
[Registering React Native Code Push with React Native Navigation by Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424554/registering-react-native-code-push-with-react-native-navigation-by-wix)

Here is my App.js code

```
  TODO: 
  SET ORIENTATION
*/

import { NetInfo, Platform } from "react-native";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";
import { registerScreens, registerScreenVisibilityListener } from "./screens";
import rootReducer from "./redux/reducers/index";
import { connectionStatusChanged } from "./redux/actions";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

registerScreens(store, Provider);
registerScreenVisibilityListener();

const handleConnectivityChange = reach => {
  store.dispatch(connectionStatusChanged(reach));
};

NetInfo.addEventListener("connectionChange", handleConnectivityChange);

export default class App {
  constructor() {
    store.subscribe(this.onStoreUpdate.bind(this));

    NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then(reach => {
      handleConnectivityChange(reach);
    });
  }

  onStoreUpdate = () => {
    const { appRoot } = store.getState().appState;

    if (this.currentRoot !== appRoot) {
      // CODE PUSH SYNC
      codePush.sync({
        updateDialog: true,
        installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
      });
      this.currentRoot = appRoot;
      this.startApp(appRoot);
    }
  };

  startApp = root => {
    // ALL MY RNN V2 SCREENS (REMOVING TO REDUCE CODE)
  } 

}
```

And here is where I register my screens and wrap the HOC with codepush

```
import React from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Linking } from "react-native";
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";
import NavigationActions from "../navigation/navigationActions";


const codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL };

function wrap(WrappedComponent, store) {
  class PP extends React.PureComponent {
    componentWillMount() {
      Linking.addEventListener("url", this.deeplinkHandler);
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        // FUNCTION HERE TO ROUTE TO ARTICLE, STRAIN, PRODUCT (when ap is closed)

        if (url) {
          const linkData = url.replace("weedup://", "").split("/");
          if (this.props.componentId === "home" && linkData[0] === "article") {
            // push component
            const { componentId } = this.props;
            NavigationActions.pushComponent({
              id: "home",
              name: "screen.Article",
              props: {
                fromDeepLink: true,
                fromBackground: false,
                article: {
                  id: linkData[1]
                }
              },
              title: "Article",
              topBarVisible: true,
              bottomTabsVisible: false
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }

    deeplinkHandler = event => {
      // FUNCTION HERE TO ROUTE TO ARTICLE, STRAIN, PRODUCT (opened)
      if (!_.isEmpty(event)) {
        const linkData = event.url.replace("weedup://", "").split("/");
        if (this.props.componentId === "home" && linkData[0] === "article") {
          const { componentId } = this.props;
          NavigationActions.pushComponent({
            id: "home",
            name: "screen.Article",
            props: {
              fromDeepLink: true,
              fromBackground: true,
              article: {
                id: linkData[1]
              }
            },
            title: "Article",
            topBarVisible: true,
            bottomTabsVisible: false
          });
        }
      }
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  return codePush(codePushOptions)(PP);
}

export const registerScreens = store => {
 // REMOVING SCREEN TO REDUCE EXAMPLE CODE
};

export function registerScreenVisibilityListener() {
  Navigation.events().registerComponentDidAppearListener(
    ({ componentName }) => {
      console.log(`Displaying screen ${componentName}`);
    }
  );
}
```

Lastly, here is my AppDelegate.m

```
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "ReactNativeNavigation.h"
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

#ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif


  return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

hey maybe I'm late to the party, but since I just stumbled across your question while integrating RNN with CodePush I thought I'd drop this here.

It looks like you're not using RNN when *not* in DEBUG, so I would simply replace your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function with this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

#ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif

  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'll give this approach a shot. Thanks for dropping it here  I still haven't completed the codepush integration because of this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the hot updates using Expo, Here is a working sample with Expo updates and React Native navigation. This project is not attached to the Expo CLI so you can use it bare React Native project

https://github.com/samithaf/expo-sample-app